# Parsing multiple xml files in Android

Tags: xml, android, saxparser

I am writing an application where I have to parse multiple xml files as a response from a server. Till now, I have written different xml parser classes for each xml depending on the tags present in different xmls ? Can I combine all xml parser classes and write a single xml parser that handles all different tags in different xmls ? Will it work? Will combining xml parser classes add an overhead because xml parser will check for every tag irrespective of whether that is part of file or not?

Comment: I guess u should tag it as xml as I dont think this has anything to with android per say. BTW which library are u using to parse the xml.

Comment: I am using SAXParser. Yes, it is a generic question.